# Adding ith element of two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists of strings.
Both lists have the same number of elements.
I want to add the ith element of the first list with the ith element of the second list.

For example:

```
list_1 = [['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['ab','bc','cd']]
list_2 = [['12','34','56'],['h','j','k'],['01','02','03']]
```

I want to get the following list:

```
list_final = [['a','b','c','12','34','56'],['1','2','3','h','j','k'],['ab','bc','cd','01','02','03']]
```

I'm aware of the for loop way of executing this(going through each element of `list_1` and adding it with the element of the same index in `list_2`), but it seems to take quite some time with long lists. Is there a faster way to do this without importing any modules.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish aside from the list manipulation you describe? When you find yourself doing difficult data manipulation in Python, there is usually a better way to structure your data from the start. If this question gets answers at all, they'll be a solution to the exact problem you posed instead of a proper solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the elements of the two lists:

```
list_final = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_1 = [['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['ab','bc','cd']]
>>> list_2 = [['12','34','56'],['h','j','k'],['01','02','03']]
>>> [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', '12', '34', '56'], ['1', '2', '3', 'h', 'j', 'k'], ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', '01', '02', '03']]
```